# Is there a way to use ACL to deny access to folders by user, preferrably by making them invisible?

Tags: linux, permissions, sftp, acl, chroot

Is there a way to use Linux's Access Control Lists feature to deny access to folders by user, preferrably by making them invisible? This is needed for a chroot SFTP environment where we want to block access